# Time To First Byte with varnish cache - 12 seconds

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, performance, full-page-cache, varnish

I installed varnish cache and verified using [official guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html).

In official guide mention **5ms** to load the url with varnish but mine it is **12s**.

**Info:**

**OS** : ubuntu 14.0.4, **webserver** : apache2, **php** : 7, **php memory_limit** : 2G, **Varnish** : varnish-4.0.5

Below attached my store front(`http://host/codebase/production`) chrome console output

[image: Easy for your reference]

what I need to tune? please feel free to post answer/comment, any help would be much appreciated, we can keep consolidating answer of tuning page load speed.

Comment: Depending on VCL you have in use, Varnish may not cache the page with subdirectory-like installation. Most likely you get ```Age: 0``` when verifying configuration - this means the page was not cached.

Comment: thanks! you right it is not cache the page, one of my extension use cacheable="false", I removed it, now ttfb reduced to 1s. I think 1s also huge load time as per the official guide. any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have positive value in ```Age: ``` now?

Comment: yes, +ve value...

Answer (score 0):

i have export varnish vcl config in backend and move it to varnish config folder

configuration in my dev enviroment
Enable all cache types
No js or css minify or bundle. Dev site no need this feature
Backend port 8080 i'm using nginx server listening 8080 port

Move magento exported file varnish.vcl (located in magentoroot/var) to /etc/varnish/ change name to default.vcl
I use ubuntu os and change default varnish port 6081 to 80 for listen all traffic user

daemon varnish config service located in /etc/varnish/default

> DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl"

Change port nignx to 8080

After that restart all service such as nginx, varnish, php

Above is all my experiences in my dev machine

Comment: thanks! I completed the configuration, varnish works but somehow ttfb 1s, but official verification mention 5ms, how to tune to achieve 5ms? that is my question

Comment: I'm not sure 5ms is theory. For clean install magento. Check system.log or exception log for more information. My local usually load around 1-2 sec